# parse nmap output for ncrack to use

Tags: xml, bash, nmap

I want to use NMAP to detect all hosts running Telnet and SSH, even if they are not using the default port.  Then I want to send the output of NMAP to a file that defines non-standard servcies for NCRACK to use.
I run NMAP with the -sV switch to detect versions and get something similar to this:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     Dropbear sshd 2015.67 (protocol 2.0)
23/tcp open  telnet?

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.133
Host is up (0.0048s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
2323/tcp open  telnet  Linux telnetd
4444/tcp open  ssh     (protocol 2.0)
```

I need to manipulate this output to create a file like this:

```
ssh://192.168.1.1:22
ssh://192.168.1.133:4444
telnet://192.168.1.1:23
telnet://192.168.1.133:2323
```

I understand that using the NMAP XML output and xmllint would help but after that I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you need to stick to bash? Because literally any fuller-featured programming language should handle this better. The only tool I found for processing XML from a shell is [xmlsh](http://www.xmlsh.org/Commands), not sure if that's easier as a dependency for you.

Comment: But also, I don't think people on SO will end up writing your script for you. From your question it's not clear you even looked at the XML output to see what parts you need from it.

Comment: @millimoose I have looked at the XML output but the interactive output seemed more readable for the purpose of asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nmap -sv | awk '/Nmap scan/ { ip=$5 } /ssh/ { split($1,arg,"/");print "ssh://"ip":"arg[1] } /telnet/ { split($1,arg,"/");print "telnet://"ip":"arg[1] }'
```

Check for pattern match of "Nmap scan" and then store ip address in variable ip. Then check for pattern matches of ssh or telnet split the first space delimited piece of data into an array arg. Print the the first element of arg along with the ip address and the words telnet or ssh.

Output:

```
 ssh://192.168.1.1:22
 telnet://192.168.1.1:23
 telnet://192.168.1.133:2323
 ssh://192.168.1.133:4444
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way too much work: [Ncrack can already parse Nmap's XML format](https://nmap.org/ncrack/man.html#idp47218432) directly, handling each open port according to the service name detected by `-sV`.

```
nmap -oX scan.xml -sV 192.168.1.0/24
ncrack -iX scan.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great too and is a lot simpler, so should be the correct answer.  But the way I asked the question I feel Raman should get the accepted answer.